# IPsec tunnel on CentOs

Tags: centos6, ipsec

I have set up an ipsec tunnel on centos 6 to a VPN which seems to be connecting correctly according to the VPN provider.

There is an SMPP service on their server within their network i need to access on (icmp port 4000) but i cannot ping or telnet to the server.  The manager of the SMPP server says i should be able to do both if the VPN is connected correctly.  According to the VPN manager, the connection is successful but there is no data being transferred.

Other than the initial ipsec setup, is there other steps would i need to take to ensure i can contact the other server?  Can i do it via the ipsec connection or do i need something like L2TP to achieve the connection?

I have added altered my iptables as advised by the VPN provider

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon May  5 09:27:57 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [866464:142452203]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [432939:1455490396]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8444 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May  5 09:27:57 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon May  5 09:27:57 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May  5 09:27:57 2014
```

I'm new to ipsec and VPN's so any info is much appreciated.

Cheers

Will

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Turns out i just needed to set the leftsourceip and the rightsourceip values in my ipsec.conf file.  Very few ipsec with StrongSwan / OpenSwan tutorials out there have this as a requirement, so it's probably not required for all implementations of ipsec.